# Where to initialize the field of a JavaBean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans

If I put the init code at `place 1`, the `beanValue` is NOT initialized.
But `place 2` works. Why?

```
public class AJavaBean {

    private String beanValue = "default bean value 1";  <==place 1

    public AJavaBean() {
        // beanValue = "default bean value 2"; <== place 2
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return beanValue;
    }

    public void setContent(String arg) {
        beanValue = arg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Clean your project. Because place 1 is copied above place 2 (if you examine the bytecode).

Comment: Seems Eclipse sometimes tricks me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work. Your "place 1" (declaration) happens first, and "place 2" (constructor) happens second. If "place 1" does not appear to be working, you must be changing it later.

The normal place to initialize instance variables is in the constructor, however you can also use an *initializer block* which happens in between the prior two (after declaration, before constructor):

```
class A {
    private int i;
    // initializer block
    {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```